# UIPopoverControl on UIButton inside UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uipopovercontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView`, in which I have numerous `UICollectionViewCell`s that each have a `UIButton` within them.  I would like to display a `UIPopoverController` each time a user presses on one of these `UIButton`.  However, when I do, the position of the `UIPopoverController` is nowhere near correct.  My guess is that it's due to a translation issue in the `CGRect` I'm using, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to correct it.  Inside my selector that is called when the `UIButton` is pressed, I have something like this...

```
UIButton *detailsButton = (UIButton *)sender;
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:detailsButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

When I do this, however, it appears to be positioned at the same place every time, regardless of the position of the `UIButton` and `UICollectionViewCell` within the `UICollectionView`.  Can someone give me some pointers as to how I can translate the position of the `UIButton` within the entirety of the `UICollectionView`?  I suppose I need the absolute position of the `detailsButton`, but am at a loss as to how to get it.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Have you tried the UIView method, convertRect:toView:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views have coordinates relative to their superview, not relative to the screen.  So if all your cells are identical, `detailsButton.frame` will be identical for all the buttons.

Try changing the `inView:` parameter.

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:detailsButton.frame inView:detailsButton.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```